# SwiftUI layout in VStack where one child is offered a maxHeight but can use less than that height

Tags: swift, layout, swiftui

I'm trying to build a layout inside a `VStack` that contains two children. The first child should take up all available space unused by the second child. The second child has a preferred size based on its own contents. I'd like to limit the height of the second child to a maximum height, but it should be able to take less than the maximum (when its own contents cannot make use of all the height). This should all be responsive to the root view size, which is the parent of the `VStack` (because the device can rotate).

My attempt uses the `.frame(maxHeight: n)` modifier, which seems to unconditionally takes up the entire `n` points of height, even when the view being modified doesn't use it. This results in whitespace rendered above and below the `VStack`'s second child. This problem is shown in the Portrait preview below - the `hasIdealSizeView` only has a height of 57.6pts, but the frame that wraps that view has a height of 75pts.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct StackWithOneLimitedHeightChild: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                fullyExpandingView
                hasIdealSizeView
                    .frame(maxHeight: geometry.size.height / 4)
            }
        }
    }
    
    var fullyExpandingView: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
    }
    
    var hasIdealSizeView: some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .aspectRatio(5/3, contentMode: .fit)
            Rectangle()
                .aspectRatio(5/3, contentMode: .fit)
        }
            // the following modifier just prints out the resulting height of this view in the layout
            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Text("Height: \(geometry.size.height)")
                        .font(.system(size: 12.0))
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct StackWithOneLimitedHeightChild_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            StackWithOneLimitedHeightChild()
                .previewDisplayName("Portrait")
                .previewLayout(PreviewLayout.fixed(width: 200, height: 300))
            StackWithOneLimitedHeightChild()
                .previewDisplayName("Landscape")
                .previewLayout(PreviewLayout.fixed(width: 300, height: 180))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Xcode Preview]

This observed result is consistent with how the `.frame(maxHeight: n)` modifier is described in the docs and online blog posts (the [flow chart here](https://swiftui-lab.com/frame-behaviors/#altering-behaviors) is extremely helpful). Nonetheless, I can't seem to find another way to build this type of layout.

**Related question**: what are the expected use cases for `.frame(maxHeight: n)`? It seems to do the opposite of what I'd expect by unconditionally wrapping the view in a frame that is at least `n` points in height. It seems no different than `.frame(height: n)`, using an explicit value for the offered height.

Comment: If second part has own fixed content size that you don't need `.frame(maxHeight:` externally at all. This modifier is to limit available area externally for dynamic content. Actually provided example is not very obvious of what you have in real scenario.

Comment: @Asperi the second child does not have a *fixed* content size, but it has some ideal height for a given width. but if that ideal height is greater than the externally supplied maxHeight (from the `.frame()` modifier), then the second child's actual height should be clamped to that maxHeight (something less than the ideal height). the second child knows how to layout its own child views to best make use of that space. you're right that the second child's contents are not dynamic, but the root view's size is dynamic so the layout is not fixed. i hope this helps clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior of .minHeight in this example is strange and far from intuitive. But I found a solution using a slightly different route:

This defines the minHeight for the expanding view (to get the desired layout in portrait mode), but adds a .layoutPriority to the second, making it define itself first and then give the remaining space to the upper view.

```
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                fullyExpandingView
                    .frame(minHeight: geometry.size.height / 4 * 3)
                hasIdealSizeView
                    .layoutPriority(1)
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This totally works for the case I've shown above and unblocks me for now. Thank you!

It's somewhat unsatisfying because the solution depends on consuming all the remaining height in the container instead of actually defining a maximum height on the item I'd like to limit. This won't work if the first child is replaced with *n* views that are all able to expand height (to different values) because the `minHeight` for each may not be calculable. If you have any thoughts on how this could be done, I'd be interested in hearing it!

Comment: hmmm ... I assumed you are aiming for a 3/4 to 1/4 height general layout. But it sounds like you want different ratios based on the large view? Can you specify what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a really short way to go about this but in the meantime here is what I did.
Firstly I created a struct for your hasIdealSizeView and I made it return a GeometryProxy, and with that i could return the height of the HStack, in this case, the same height you were printing on to the Text View. then with that I used the return proxy to check if the height is greater than the maximum, and if it is, i set it to the maximum, otherwise, set the height to nil, which basically allows the native SwiftUI flexible height:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Test
//
//  Created by Denzel Anderson on 3/16/22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct StackWithOneLimitedHeightChild: View {
    
    @State var viewHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                fullyExpandingView
                    .overlay(Text("\(viewHeight)"))
                //                GeometryReader { geo in
                hasIdealSizeView { proxy in
                    viewHeight = proxy.size.height
                }
                .frame(height: viewHeight > geometry.size.height / 4 ? geometry.size.height / 4:nil)
            }
            .background(Color.green)
        }
    }
    
    
    var fullyExpandingView: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
    }
    
}
struct hasIdealSizeView:  View {
    
    var height: (GeometryProxy)->()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.white)
                .aspectRatio(5/3, contentMode: .fit)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.white)
                .aspectRatio(5/3, contentMode: .fit)
        }
        
        // the following modifier just prints out the resulting height of this view in the layout
        .overlay(alignment: .center) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Text("Height: \(geometry.size.height)")
                    .font(.system(size: 12.0))
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .onAppear {
                        height(geometry)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty creative solution, thanks for sharing! I think I see one big drawback though - there's a chicken and egg problem between `hasIdealSizeView` and `StackWithOneLimitedHeightChild`. `hasIdealSizeView`'s size depends on `viewHeight` and `viewHeight` depends on the size of `hasIdeaSizeView`. I think it works out in this case because `onAppear{}` only gets called once for the lifetime of `hasIdealSizeView`, so there's no infinite recursion. I'm hoping for something a bit cleaner though.